# Dynamically Allocation and GSL(Gnu Scientific Library)

Tags: c, memory-management, gsl

So, I have to use this function from GSL.
This one:

```
gsl_matrix_view_array (double * base, size_t n1, size_t n2)
```

The first argument (`double * base`) is the matrix I need to pass to it, which is read as input from the user.

I'm dynamically allocating it this way:

```
double **base;
base = malloc(size*sizeof(double*));

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
base[i] = malloc(size*sizeof(double));
```

Where size is given by the user.
But then, when the code runs, it warns this :

```
  "passing arg 1 of gsl_matrix_view_array from incompatible pointer type".
```

What is happening?

Comment: Don't cast the result of malloc in C: http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1025391

Comment: Perhaps show the actual line of code *that is flagging the error* ? And I'm assuming your fundamental problem is you should be allocating a `double[]` that is magnitude `n1*n2`, your matrix in row-major storage order. I've never used the API, but the parameter list certainly suggests that is the case.  The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Matrix-views.html) for the function notes even shows it as row-major stored : `m'(i,j) = base[i*n2 + j]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function expects a flat array, e.g., `double arr[size*size];`.

Here's an example from the documentation that I have slightly modified to use a matrix view:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

int main(void) {
  int i, j; 

  double *arr = malloc(10 * 3 * sizeof*arr);
  gsl_matrix_view mv = gsl_matrix_view_array(arr, 10, 3);
  gsl_matrix * m = &(mv.matrix);

  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
      gsl_matrix_set(m, i, j, 0.23 + 100*i + j);

  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
      printf("m(%d,%d) = %g\n", i, j, gsl_matrix_get(m, i, j));

  free(arr);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that you can also directly allocate memory for the matrix using the provided API.

Here's the original example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, j; 

  gsl_matrix * m = gsl_matrix_alloc(10, 3);

  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
      gsl_matrix_set(m, i, j, 0.23 + 100*i + j);

  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
      printf("m(%d,%d) = %g\n", i, j, gsl_matrix_get(m, i, j));

  gsl_matrix_free(m);

  return 0;
}
```

For reference:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Matrix-views.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Matrix-allocation.html#Matrix-allocation
- http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Accessing-matrix-elements.html#Accessing-matrix-elements

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I misunderstood the API a bit. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

[**gsl_matrix_view_array**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Matrix-views.html) expects your matrix as a contiguous single allocation in row-major order. You should be allocating your array like this:

```
double (*ar)[size] = malloc(sizeof(ar[size]) * size);
```

Then (after populating it)

```
gsl_matrix_view_array(ar[0], size, size);
```

Finally, free your allocation when done with a single call:

```
free(ar);
```

Note: Don't try this with C++, as VLA's aren't standard-supported for that language.

Comment: shouldn't it be just `double * ar = malloc(sizeof(double) * size * size);` ?

Comment: @moooeeeep if you want to do the math yourself for row/column indexing, you certainly can. (as their documentation shows). either work, this just adds the ability to use `ar[i][j]` addressing, but certainly you can just use a `double*` and address with `ar[i*size+j]` instead (and in fact it would be portable across C and C++).

Comment: Apparantly it is intended to use the GSL functions for element access `gsl_matrix_set()`, `gsl_matrix_get()` etc. on the matrix view: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref_8.html#SEC186

Comment: @moooeeeep for a `gsl_matrix` that would certainly make sense. I would hope they implemented that as a macro or inlined, or the performance would be hideous. For a double base array the linear backdrop presented form of the allocation in this answer, or a raw `double*`, will be the same, and is standard-compliant. Think they have enough ways in that lib to make/access a matrix? =P. +1 on your answer btw, GJ seeing the question that wasn't asked, but should have been!